# Spring boot application on hosting side shutdown after JPA EntityManagerFactory is closed

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jar, hosting, java-17

I've moved my spring boot application to hosting https://www.mydevil.net/. App connects with MySql database which is placed on hosting as well. The problem is that after about 25 minutes it shut down. I can see in logs  JPA EntityManagerFactory close and app is closed after that.

Below I've pasted few last lines from logs:

```
INFO |2023-08-26 18:43:18,697||LifecycleService|[77.79.227.179]:5701 [dev] [5.3.1] [77.79.227.179]:5701 is STARTED
WARN |2023-08-26 18:43:18,888||JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration|spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure sp>
INFO |2023-08-26 18:43:19,753||DefaultSecurityFilterChain|Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@19105a87, org.springframework.security.web.context.request>
INFO |2023-08-26 18:43:20,066||TomcatWebServer|Tomcat started on port(s): 8001 (http) with context path ''
INFO |2023-08-26 18:43:20,085||InvestmentSupportSystemApplication|Started InvestmentSupportSystemApplication in 14.725 seconds (process running for 15.379)
INFO |2023-08-26 18:43:21,187||[/]|Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO |2023-08-26 18:43:21,187||DispatcherServlet|Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO |2023-08-26 18:43:21,189||DispatcherServlet|Completed initialization in 2 ms
WARN |2023-08-26 18:43:21,653|423D8F64576D4AA2B1F8E86E14A23222|AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor|[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8001-exec-1][home.html] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "navbar.html ::>
WARN |2023-08-26 18:43:26,972|36B91A49047B454BB7A7714A471EFE23|query|HHH90003004: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory
WARN |2023-08-26 18:43:26,994|36B91A49047B454BB7A7714A471EFE23|AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor|[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8001-exec-4][tracked_symbols] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "navbar.h>
WARN |2023-08-26 18:43:27,011|36B91A49047B454BB7A7714A471EFE23|AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor|[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8001-exec-4][tracked_symbols] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "modal/tr>
WARN |2023-08-26 18:43:33,472|9C5108BC668B417CA8ECB595E0823AE4|query|HHH90003004: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory
WARN |2023-08-26 18:43:33,478|9C5108BC668B417CA8ECB595E0823AE4|AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor|[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8001-exec-2][tracked_symbols] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "navbar.h>
WARN |2023-08-26 18:43:33,484|9C5108BC668B417CA8ECB595E0823AE4|AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor|[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8001-exec-2][tracked_symbols] Deprecated unwrapped fragment expression "modal/tr>
INFO |2023-08-26 19:07:01,509||LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean|Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
INFO |2023-08-26 19:07:01,511||HikariDataSource|HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
INFO |2023-08-26 19:07:01,516||HikariDataSource|HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I'm working with Java 17, Spring boot v.3.02.

I'm using embedded in spring boot apache tomcat.
Command I'm starting application on server side:

```
java -jar investmentsupportsystem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > log.log 2>&1 &
```

Below I've pasted my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kmichalski</groupId>
    <artifactId>investmentsupportsystem</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>investmentsupportsystem</name>
    <description>System for supporting investor</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.35.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-multiselect</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.24.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application-prod.properites looks like:

```
server.port=8001
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://myHostName:3306/databaseName
spring.datasource.username=myUserName
spring.datasource.password=myPasssword
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

# JDBC Batching
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true

#flyway config
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.flyway.user=myUserName
spring.flyway.password=MyPasswordName    
# Logging pattern for console
logging.pattern.console=%-5p|%date{ISO8601}|%X{Slf4jMDCFilter.UUID}|%logger{0}|%m%ex%n

#Last tick api url:

last_tick_api.url=http://localhost:5000

#Hazelcast queue
xtb_queue_name=queue_name
```

What can caused this shutdown? Has anyone idea what can be wrong. I would be grateful for help